# Xcode debugging: View value of NSNumber?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, debugging, nsnumber, data-formatters

Is it possible to see the numeric value of an NSNumber in the debugger datatip on in the variable watch window?

I store an Integer value in NSNumber and want to see this value during debugging.

I tried some of the data formatters in the debugger already, but it wasn't much help.

Comment: This already works in the summary column in the debugger window or inline data tip when you hover over the variable in your editor. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the Debugger view and in the Summary column enter

```
{(int)[$VAR intValue]}
```

or whatever interpretation is most appropriate for what you want to see in the Debugger.