# Why is [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] reported as null by debugger?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, boolean, nsnumber

After running these two lines in Xcode 4.6.3, both `x` and `y` are marked as `(null)` with grey text in the debugger’s *Variables View* pane.

```
  NSNumber* y = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
  NSNumber* z = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
```

Ditto for:

```
  NSNumber* literalYes = @YES;
  NSNumber* literalNo = @NO;
```

Yet if I context-click on those items in the *Variables View* pane, and from the context menu choose `Print Description`, I do see the correct `1` or `0` value.

Why does the debugger’s *Variables View* pane report these objects as `null` when they are not?

Comment: Do not trust the variables view. Better print the value/description of the variable from the debug console or right click it in the variables view and print it from there.

Comment: set breakpoint after this code and make "po y" + enter (this is print object command) in your debugger console view and make sure, I believe it's actually cannot be null

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753153/xcode-debugging-view-value-of-nsnumber

Comment: If you are running in Release mode you wont be able to see variables value in left pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4 **debugger lies**. (See comment above by [Herrman Klecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854396/hermann-klecker))

Ignore the grey color text "(null)".

Look at this question, [Xcode debugging: View value of NSNumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753153/xcode-debugging-view-value-of-nsnumber), for tips on displaying actual values.

One way…
Set breakpoint after your code, click into the debugger Console View, and use the Print Object command by typing `po y`. Press Return/Enter to execute the expression and see resulting value in the console. The commands `p` and `po` work in both the older `gdb` and newer `lldb` debugger technologies. See [Debugging tips for Objective-C programming](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/debugging-tips-for-objective-c.html) for examples.

Another way…
Open the Debugger view and in the Summary column enter something like:
`{(int)[$VAR intValue]}`