# SBData is wrong when SBValue comes from a Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, lldb

I'm trying to write a Python function to format a `Foundation.Decimal`, for use as a type summarizer. I posted it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52749749/77567). I'll also include it at the bottom of this answer, with extra debug prints.

I've now discovered a bug, but I don't know if the bug is in my function, or in lldb, or possibly in the Swift compiler.

Here's a transcript that demonstrates the bug. I load my type summarizer in `~/.lldbinit`, so the Swift REPL uses it.

```
:; xcrun swift
registering Decimal type summaries
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.11.37.1 clang-1000.11.45.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let dec: Decimal = 7
dec: Decimal = 7
```

Above, the `7` in the debugger output is from my type summarizer and is correct.

```
  3> var dict = [String: Decimal]()
dict: [String : Decimal] = 0 key/value pairs
  4> dict["x"] = dec
  5> dict["x"]
$R0: Decimal? = 7
```

Above, the `7` is again from my type summarizer, and is correct.

```
  6> dict
$R1: [String : Decimal] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "x"
    value = 0
  }
}
```

Above, the `0` (in `value = 0`) is from my type summarizer, and is **incorrect**. It should be `7`.

So why is it zero? My Python function is given an `SBValue`. It calls `GetData()` on the `SBValue` to get an `SBData`. I added debug prints to the function to print the bytes in the `SBData`, and also to print the result of `sbValue.GetLoadAddress()`. Here's the transcript with these debug prints:

```
:; xcrun swift
registering Decimal type summaries
Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.11.37.1 clang-1000.11.45.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> let dec: Decimal = 7
dec: Decimal =    loadAddress: ffffffffffffffff
    data: 00 21 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 7
```

Above, we can see that the load address is bogus, but the bytes of the `SBData` are correct (byte 1, `21`, contains the length and flags; byte 4, '07', is the first byte of the significand).

```
  3> var dict = [String: Decimal]()
dict: [String : Decimal] = 0 key/value pairs
  4> dict["x"] = dec
  5> dict
$R0: [String : Decimal] = 1 key/value pair {
  [0] = {
    key = "x"
    value =    loadAddress: ffffffffffffffff
    data: 00 00 00 00 00 21 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 0
  }
}
```

Above, we can see that the load address is still bogus, and now the bytes of the `SBData` are incorrect. The `SBData` still contains 20 bytes (the correct number for a `Foundation.Decimal`, aka `NSDecimal`), but now four `00` bytes have been inserted at the front and the last four bytes have been dropped.

So here are my specific questions:

1. Am I using the lldb API incorrectly, and thus getting wrong answers? If so, what am I doing wrong and how should I correct it?
2. If I'm using the lldb API correctly, then is this a bug in lldb, or is the Swift compiler emitting incorrect metadata? How can I figure out which tool has the bug? (Because if it's a bug in one of the tools, I'd like to file a bug report.)
3. If it's a bug in lldb or Swift, how can I work around the problem so I can format a `Decimal` correctly when it's part of a `Dictionary`?

---

Here is my type formatter, with debug prints:

```
# Decimal / NSDecimal support for lldb
#
# Put this file somewhere, e.g. ~/.../lldb/Decimal.py
# Then add this line to ~/.lldbinit:
#     command script import ~/.../lldb/Decimal.py

import lldb

def stringForDecimal(sbValue, internal_dict):
    from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

    print('    loadAddress: %x' % sbValue.GetLoadAddress())

    sbData = sbValue.GetData()
    if not sbData.IsValid():
        raise Exception('unable to get data: ' + sbError.GetCString())
    if sbData.GetByteSize() != 20:
        raise Exception('expected data to be 20 bytes but found ' + repr(sbData.GetByteSize()))

    sbError = lldb.SBError()
    exponent = sbData.GetSignedInt8(sbError, 0)
    if sbError.Fail():
        raise Exception('unable to read exponent byte: ' + sbError.GetCString())

    flags = sbData.GetUnsignedInt8(sbError, 1)
    if sbError.Fail():
        raise Exception('unable to read flags byte: ' + sbError.GetCString())
    length = flags & 0xf
    isNegative = (flags & 0x10) != 0

    debugString = ''
    for i in range(20):
        debugString += ' %02x' % sbData.GetUnsignedInt8(sbError, i)
    print('    data:' + debugString)

    if length == 0 and isNegative:
        return 'NaN'

    if length == 0:
        return '0'

    getcontext().prec = 200
    value = Decimal(0)
    scale = Decimal(1)
    for i in range(length):
        digit = sbData.GetUnsignedInt16(sbError, 4 + 2 * i)
        if sbError.Fail():
            raise Exception('unable to read memory: ' + sbError.GetCString())
        value += scale * Decimal(digit)
        scale *= 65536

    value = value.scaleb(exponent)
    if isNegative:
        value = -value

    return str(value)

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internal_dict):
    print('registering Decimal type summaries')
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add Foundation.Decimal -F "' + __name__ + '.stringForDecimal"')
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add NSDecimal -F "' + __name__ + '.stringForDecimal"')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an lldb bug.  Please file a bug about this against lldb with http://bugs.swift.org.

For background: there is some magic going on behind your back in the Dictionary case.  I can't show this in the REPL, but if you have a [String : Decimal] array as a local variable in some real code and do:

```
(lldb) frame variable --raw dec_array
(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Foundation.Decimal>) dec_array = {
  _variantBuffer = native {
    native = {
      _storage = 0x0000000100d05780 {
        Swift._SwiftNativeNSDictionary = {}
        bucketCount = {
          _value = 2
        }
        count = {
          _value = 1
        }
        initializedEntries = {
          values = {
            _rawValue = 0x0000000100d057d0
          }
          bitCount = {
            _value = 2
          }
        }
        keys = {
          _rawValue = 0x0000000100d057d8
        }
        values = {
          _rawValue = 0x0000000100d057f8
        }
        seed = {
          0 = {
            _value = -5794706384231184310
          }
          1 = {
            _value = 8361200869849021207
          }
        }
      }
    }
    cocoa = {
      cocoaDictionary = 0x00000001000021b0
    }
  }
}
```

A swift Dictionary doesn't actually contain the dictionary elements anywhere obvious, and certainly not as ivars.  So lldb has a "Synthetic child provider" for Swift Dictionaries that makes up SBValues for the keys and values of the Dictionary, and it is one of those synthetic children that your formatter is being handed.

That's also why the load address is -1.  That really means "this is a synthetic thing whose data lldb is directly managing, not a thing at an address somewhere in your program."  The same thing is true of REPL results, they are more a fiction lldb maintains.  But if you looked at a local variable of type Decimal, you would see a valid load address, because it is a thing that lives somewhere in memory.

Anyway, so apparently the Synthetic children Decimal objects we are making up to represent the values of the dictionary don't set the start of the data correctly.  Interestingly enough, if you make a [Decimal : String] dictionary, the key field's SBData is correct, and your formatter works.  It's just the values that aren't right.

I tried the same thing with Dictionaries that have Strings as values, and the SBData looks correct there.  So there's something funny about Decimal.  Anyway, thanks for pursuing this, and please do file a bug.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I filed [SR-8989](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8989). I take it you don't know of a workaround. 

Comment: Thanks for the radar.  I can't think of a way to work around this.  Since you don't know where the real bits for the dictionary elements live, you can't just back up a bit or something like that.  This needs to be fixed on the lldb end.